# Multi.Threading windows form seperate memory for i variable

Tags: c#

I am new to c# programming. The variables in the calling functions gets changed when I call the function from multiple threads. Ie, when we use a single thread, the program correctly goes from 1 to 100 but when I run more than 100 threads, the program escapes some of the i variable values. I want to have separate memory for each threads calling `threadproc()` so that all of the value of variable `i` will be incremented independently on all the threads.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    for (int threadloop = 1; threadloop <= Convert.ToInt32(threadcnttxt.Text); threadloop++)
    {
        //Thread th;
        Thread th  = new Thread(threadproc);
        //th.IsBackground = true;
        th.Start();
    }
       // th.Join();
    MessageBox.Show("End of Code reached.");
}

public void threadproc()
{

    for (int iterateloop = 0; iterateloop < 10; iterateloop++)
    {
        //if i run this function for 4 threads it should store 40000 in the dummy table but the application just stores less records would be due to locks..
        var requestresult = TService(strarr[iterateloop].ToString()); //Here i pass ith element of array to TService function.

        sql = "insert into dbo.dummy values(" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + "," + requestresult + ")";
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();//command.ExecuteReaderAsync();


    }
}

public requestResult TService(string enquiryline)
{
    string requestResult = "";
    int X = 0;  //what to do with these local variable????? should i lock these also?
    X = 1st element of enquiryline; // Eg of enquiryline 1,client name,xxx,other details comma delimited string


    requestResult = sendrequest(enquiryline);
    return requestResult;
}
```

Comment: This won't compile. What is **iterateLoop**? also you're not incrementing **i** so that loop goes on forever!

Comment: There's nothing in your code example that involves shared access to any data, so no synchronization/locking/cross-thread issues exist. Of course, as has been pointed out, the code also wouldn't compile as-is ("iterateloop" isn't declared anywhere). But if you want help with a real threading issue, you need to post a proper concise-but-complete code example.